# ¿Porque Visual Studio Code no crea un archivo .txt con python?

Tags: python, archivo, vscode

Me he encontrado con este problema al querer hacer que mi programa cree un archivo de texto y se guarde información ahí, al ejecutarlo se supone que en la carpeta que tengo guardado ese archivo se creara un archivo `.txt` pero no lo crea.

*Soy estudiante de programación y seria de gran ayuda que alguien me ayude a encontrar una solución para mi proyecto.*

Adjunto el código que he empleado.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
from io import open
import msvcrt #libreria que incluye la funcion de presionar tecla para continuar
def menu():
    Print("Administrador de conjunto de viviendas")


   while(True):
        print("1.- Ingresar nuevo directorio")
        print("2.- eliminar directorio")
        print("3.- consultar directorio")
        print("4.- buscar un registro existente")
        print("5.- Modificar registros")
        print("6.- Salir")
        opcion=int(input("Seleccione una opcion"))
        if opcion==1:
            os.system('cls')
            #print("Aqui ira la funcion de ingresar nuevos directorios")
            ingresar_nuevodir()
            #print("Presione una Esc para continuar...")

            os.system('cls')
            pulsar_Esc()
        elif opcion==2:
            os.system('cls')
            #print("Aqui ira la funcion de eliminar directorios")

            #print("Presione una Esc para continuar...")
            pulsar_Esc()
            os.system('cls')
            elif opcion==3:
            os.system('cls')
            #print("Aqui ira la funcion de consultar registros")

            #print("Presione una Esc para continuar..")
            pulsar_Esc()
            os.system('cls')
        elif opcion==4:
            os.system('cls')
            print("Aqui ira la funcion de buscar un registro existente")

            #print("Presione una Esc para continuar...")
            pulsar_Esc()
           os.system('cls')
        elif opcion==5:
           os.system('cls')
           print("Aqui ira la funcion de modificar los registros")

           #print("Presione una Esc para continuar..")
           pulsar_Esc()
           os.system('cls')
        elif opcion==6:
           os.system('cls')
           sys.exit()                

#creacion de la funcion en la que me creara un archivo txt y podra   agregar informacion
def ingresar_nuevodir():
    archivo_texto=open("datos.txt","w")
    frase =input("ingrese el numero de una vivienda")
    archivo_texto.write(frase)
    archivo_texto.close()

#creacion de funcion aplatar una tecla especifica para continuar
def pulsar_Esc():
    print("Presione '+' para continuar...")
    key = None
    while key != '+':

        key = msvcrt.getwch()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He probado tu código, y ha funcionado correctamente, cada vez que quieras que una función se ejecute, es decir, que haga algo, debes de mandar a llamarla:

```py
#Se define la función
def ingresar_nuevodir():
    archivo_texto=open("datos.txt","w")
    frase =input("ingrese el numero de una vivienda")
    archivo_texto.write(frase)
    archivo_texto.close()
```

Después en el código:

```py
ingresar_nuevodir()
```

Se manda a llamar la función solo con escribir su nombre, de no ser llamada esta existirá pero no se ejecutará nada del código que exista dentro de ella.

Te dejo una prueba donde ejecuto el código en el mismo IDE que tu:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Información sobre funciones en Python](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/python/capitulo-4/definiendo-funciones)

**EDIT:**

Como bien menciona [@Name_Not_Found](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/27176/name-not-found) python al ser un [lenguaje interpretado](https://es.quora.com/Qu%C3%A9-significa-que-python-es-un-lenguaje-interpretado) es necesario que la función esté declarada antes de ser llamada. Entonces el código final quedarías más o menos.

```py
#Declarada antes del ciclo que hace uso de la función
def ingresar_nuevodir():
    archivo_texto=open("datos.txt","w")
    frase =input("ingrese el numero de una vivienda")
    archivo_texto.write(frase)
    archivo_texto.close()

#Demás funciones a usar

while (True):
#Acciones
```

Comment: En el programa principal que tengo, si estoy mandando a llamar a la funcion, pero aun asi sigue sin crearme el archivo .txt, la funcion se encuentra llamada en la opcion 1 del menu, pondre en el ejemplo el codigo completo.

Comment: Puedes compartir también el código de cuando llamas a la función?

Comment: Ya lo comparti en este momento

Comment: Funciona igual mal si es que pones la función antes del while?

Comment: Funciona, se crea el archivo txt y se guarda, pero la idea es que se cree cuando escoja la opcion 1

Comment: Me refiero si es que declaras la función antes del ciclo while, no llamarla, eso ya lo hace la opción 1, ya que copie tu código y me salto un error, así que he puesto la declaracion de la funcion antes del while y ha funcionado

Comment: Es tal cual como dice @Riaven, Python al ser un lenguaje interpretado, la definición de la función debe estar antes del llamado a la función, es por eso que no funciona, no es porque se trate de VS Code.

Comment: Ha funcionado Amigo, muchas gracias, creia que no importaba el orden al codificar funciones siempre y cuando sea llamada, deberas gracias :)

Comment: Gracias por la paciencia @Riaven recien estoy empezando en  la programacion :D

Answer (score 0):

Dando y dando al fin encontre el error que estas teniendo, resulta que con visual studio code, es necesario que le pases la ruta completa donde crearás el archivo, es decir así:

```py
archivo_texto = open(r"C:\directorio\carpeta\archivo.txt", "w")
```

Probandolo asi funcionara tu código.

Comment: No es necesario, si no se especifica la ruta absoluta python lo interpretará como una ruta relativa

Comment: De hecho si python lo interpreta como una ruta relativa, pero el IDE de visual studio code requiere colocar la ruta, de otra forma no trabaja con el paquete io, a que se debe? ni idea pero probandolo con la ruta completa funciona el codigo que coloco